# How to get rid of the "No bootable medium found!" error in Virtual Box?

Tags: solaris, virtualbox

I am working withing Oracle VM Virtual box on Solaris 11. When the battery of my laptop became 0%  and I wasn't beside my laptop, the system halted. So when I started the session I got the following:

```
Fatal: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

The problem is I already have a script written there.. Is there a way that I can get it back ?

Comment: i think that you should change/add the tag to virtual box.. it would be helpful

Comment: It won't help in your case, but for people coming here from Google, make sure that you select Linux and Ubuntu when you're creating the virtual machine.

Answer (score 18):

Follow the steps below:

1) Select your VM Instance. Go to `Settings->Storage`

2) Under the storage tree select the `default image or "Empty"`(which ever is present)

3) Under the attributes frame, click on the CD image and select "`Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file`"

4) Browse and select the image file(iso or what ever format) from the system

5) Select OK.

Abishek's solution is correct. But the highlighted area in 2nd image could be misleading.

Comment: If you still get the error even after choosing the iso, it might be an inappropriate iso for the machine (for example, by mistake I tried to use an `arm64` iso instead of `amd64`, and it didn't give any errors except continuing to show "Fatal: No bootable medium found! System halted" as if I had no iso selected

Answer (score 14):

***FIX 1:***

**Step1:** Go to settings > then select the following configuration(Disable Floppy)

[image: Config]

Alternatively, you can press F12 while booting the Guest OS and select CD from there, this is a one time setting, good enough for the installation.

**Step 2:** Place your Existing Guest OS bootable CD in the Disk Drive and start the Guest OS.

***FIX 2:***

Go to Settings > And Perform the following:

[image: Config1]

***FIX 3:***

Try Fix 1 & 2 together..

Comment: ok i will try the above steps but can u provide me with a way to recover my script ? thank you

Comment: once your OS starts working you may recover it.. otherwise its quite impossible, unless you had already installed a guest addition, and stored your scripts there!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is grey, I can't select anything !

Comment: when i start the OS , it displays the fatal mess ... then i go to settings and I get everything in grey

Comment: i rebooted the system again ,and started working in a terminal, but when I typed the directory where my script is, there was no such file or directory.

Comment: try command "locate filename.ext"

Comment: i'm in bash , locate doesn't exist

Comment: ummm..use ls..to check in the specified directory..else i am not sure what to advice..

Comment: For me, I can select/deselect those options. Everything is disabled. Any hint?

Comment: @rabinutam If it is gray, simply close out of your virtual device, then navigate to settings and perform the operation Abhishek suggests, and then it should work :)

Answer (score 4):

Kind of an embarrassing occurrence of this error for me, but if it helps the cause...

Make sure you have Ubuntu for desktop, part 1 of this wikihow:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

A part I may or may not have skipped, along with part 4 (selecting the Ubuntu ISO as the CD Load)

Nobody's perfect :)

Comment: It's not good practice to just use a link to an external site as your answer as it's far too easy for links to break in future.  If possible, please try to capture the salient points in your answer here.

Comment: Also, there is no mention of Ubuntu in the question, so it doesn't address either the issue specifically asked for or the more generic case.

Comment: Harsh...

Emphasis on the "occurence of this error for me"

Also I describe the steps I skipped, a bit concisely but adequately.

Comment: My two points above are valid.  Your answer here is a wrapper for an externally linked web site and it _doesn't_ answer the original question.  If you wish to give a solution to _your_ problem, write your own self-answered question. If you fix your answer to _this_ question, I will cheerfully remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The CD / DVD wanted to be on the IDE controller on my system, not the SATA controller

Comment: +1 to this; also enable the 'Live CD' tick box. Definitely wouldn't run from SATA.

Comment: what does this mean "wanted to be on". Do you mean put the vdi under IDE rather than SATA, and then it worked?

Comment: Too long ago (i.e. >48 hours) to remember. Reading it I'd say yes. Just try it, your kittens should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It's Never late.
This error shows that you have After Installation of OS in Virtual Box you Remove the ISO file from Virtual Box Setting or you change your OS ISO file location.
Thus you can Solve your Problem bY following given steps or you can watch video at [Link](https://youtu.be/pW3V161JF8I)

1. Open Virtual Box and Select you OS from List in Left side.
2. Then Select Setting. (setting Windows will open)
3. The Select on "Storage" From Left side Panel.
4. Then select on "empty" disk Icon on Right side panel.
5. Under "Attribute" Section you can See another Disk icon. select o it.
6. Then Select on "Choose Virtual Optical Disk file" and Select your OS ISO file.
7. Restart VirtualBox and Start you OS.

To watch Video click on Below link: [Link](https://youtu.be/pW3V161JF8I)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Go to virtual box > right click the OS > settings > under one of the many tab that I don't remember(sorry for this, i dont have vbox installed)> locate the VDI (virtual box disk image) file..

and save the settings.. then try to start the OS..

Comment: it didn't work. Is there another way ?

Comment: i cant tell you until tomorrow...my office pc has virtual box..i l go and check the way. for now try to create a clone and start the clone..the clone will have all your files and it wont be deleted..

Comment: how can i create a clone ? I'm new to this :s

Comment: right click on your OS inside VBox.. then click on clone, then enter clone name, tick reinitializa mac address(optional), next select full clone and ok.. wait for 30 seconds and your clone is ready..

Comment: How about the script that I wrote before? how can i get it back? I did the clone , it has now the one that says Fatal: no bootable ....

Comment: umm this is a critical problem..ur script will be inside the OS..there must be a solution..i l check it reply.within 8 hours.. sorry for the delay

Comment: no problem I'll wait. thank you :)